# will the app store reject my app if I use a javascript sdk for the backend?

Tags: javascript, appstore-approval, mbaas

I'm using Trigger.io to make an app I can deploy to both the app store and google play. 
I'm researching baas backends that offer native sdk's for android and apple, but also offer javascript sdk's which I assume are meant for things like Trigger or Phonegap. 
My question is do the app store guidelines favor one kind of back end service over another? Is javascript risky for backend? I just want to be sure before I pay for a service. The services I'm considering are cloudmine and shephertz.

Comment: The app stores won't reject your app based on what technologies you're using. There are tons of apps that use javascript i.e. webviews embedded in an app's main container and even the server side code. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They shouldn't know anything about your back-end web service.

Sounds like you are talking about making a [hybird app](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/) though, which is also fine (and is technically a client). There are a ton of hybrid frameworks out there: Ionic, Cordova, Cocoon, PhoneGap, apparently Trigger.io, etc. They wouldn't be useful if app stores rejected them.

Comment: ok... so it won't reject my app if I write all my backend code in javascript? That's all I want to know.

Comment: Yep! You're safe. I understand the hesitation, it's hard to know sometimes. But that's the purpose of these frameworks: to publish web-apps onto app stores. If that answer helped, please accept & upvote. GLHF!